# Jenkins appears to be skipping permissions setting commands

Tags: bash, jenkins

We are using jenkins to deploy our application. When there are only a few files uploaded on the website it works perfectly fine. Where there are quite a few files (currently we have approx 3.9GB) jenkins appears to skip the command which set the permissions on the files and folders. These are the 2 commands from the bash script in question:

```
sudo find /path/to/web/root -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
sudo find /path/to/web/root -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
```

We can tell the commands aren't running as the site serves 403 errors on the files when accessed.

When we run the command manually afterwards it runs absolutely fine (although it does take about 2-3 mins to run the first one)

Comment: Blind guess, maybe something timeout related? Try to add some debug output to those lines, maybe the upload process is still running when jenkins decides that it timed out and it executes the commands too early or something along these lines? Also, if you really need it to work quick and dirty, try if you can add it in a seperate job which you trigger in a post build event, with a quiet time set to some arbitrary value, i.e. some minutes. Long enough that you can be sure the upload will be done.

Comment: Combine them into a single `find`. `-type f -exec ... \; -o -type d -exec ... \;`. There's no need to do all the `find` work twice.